# Change language form user selection in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

in my app i have two languages(english,arabic).if user select anyone language the application change that language.but my application contents are retrieve data from json api.how to change it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar59J.png)

```
    package com.blog.navdrawer;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.blog.navdrawer.JSONParser;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Locale;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
import static com.blog.navdrawer.R.string.language;

/**
 * Created by ewall-07 on 3/12/16.
 */
public class DemoFragone extends Fragment {



    private JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
    private TextView tv,tv1;

    String a,b,c;
    private JSONObject jsonobject = null;

    String languagesave;
    private Locale myLocale;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragone,container,false);


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragone,container,false);
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_tv);
        tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_tv1);
        new retrievedata().execute();

       language();
/*

        //it help us to change the font style...
        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"DroidSerif-Regular.ttf");
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_tv1);
        tv1.setTypeface(type);*/
        return v;




    }

    private void language() {

        String langPref = "Language";
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.file_Save),MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(getString(R.string.language),languagesave);
        editor.commit();
    }





    class retrievedata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {




            if(languagesave == "en") {

                jsonobject = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cegNjwgBTS?indent=2");

                Log.d("app data", jsonobject.toString());

                try {

                    a = jsonobject.getString("name");
                    b = jsonobject.getString("data");
                    c = jsonobject.getString("image_url");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else if(languagesave == "ar"){
                    jsonobject = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cegNjwgBTS?indent=2");

                    Log.d("app data", jsonobject.toString());

                    try {

                        a = jsonobject.getString("name_ar");
                        b = jsonobject.getString("data_ar");
                        c = jsonobject.getString("image_url");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            return a;
        }
        protected  void onPostExecute(String a){
            tv.setText(a);
            tv1.setText(b);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.image_one);
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(c).error(R.drawable.error).placeholder(R.drawable.progress_aniamtion).noFade().into(image);
        }
        }

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (myLocale != null){
        newConfig.locale = myLocale;
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        getActivity().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

}
}

```
MainActivity :

package com.blog.navdrawer.activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.blog.navdrawer.R;
import com.blog.navdrawer.adapter.CountryLanguageAdapter;

public class CountryLanguageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button mSaveButton;
    private ListView mCountryList, mLanguageList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mLanguageAdapter, mCountryAdaptor;
    String languagesave;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addActionbar();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_country_language);
        initialization();
    }

    private void addActionbar() {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
        TextView TvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(getResources()
                .getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", getPackageName()));
    }

    private void initialization() {

       //ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
       // bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#f79f04")));
       //bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
       //bar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);

        mCountryList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_country);
        mLanguageList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_language);
        mSaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save_continue);

        String[] country = { "Saudi Arabia - Riyadh", "Kuwait", "Qatar", "Bahrain" };
        String[] language   = { "English", "Arabic"};
        int[] countryIcon = { R.drawable.ic_saudi, R.drawable.ic_kuwait , R.drawable.ic_qatar, R.drawable.ic_bahrain};
        int[] languageIcon = { R.drawable.ic_english, R.drawable.ic_arabic };
        int countryList = 1;
        int languageList = 2;
        String[] languagesave = language;

        //Create a customer adapter for the language list
        mLanguageAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, country);
        mCountryList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        mCountryList.setAdapter(new CountryLanguageAdapter(CountryLanguageActivity.this, country, countryIcon, countryList));
        //Create a customer adapter for the country list
        mCountryAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, language);
        mLanguageList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        mLanguageList.setAdapter(new CountryLanguageAdapter(CountryLanguageActivity.this, language, languageIcon, languageList));

        ViewTreeObserver listVTO = mCountryList.getViewTreeObserver();
        listVTO.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mCountryList.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                resizeListView(mCountryList);
            }
        });

        ViewTreeObserver listVTO1 = mLanguageList.getViewTreeObserver();
        listVTO1.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mLanguageList.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                resizeListView(mLanguageList);
            }
        });

        mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = CountryLanguageActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.file_Save),MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(getString(R.string.language),languagesave);
        editor.commit();

    }

    //onclick even for the save and continue button
    public void onClick(View v ) {
        //ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
        //alert.showDialog(ListViewMultipleSelectionActivity.this, "Please select the country");
        Intent intent = new Intent(CountryLanguageActivity.this,LeftRightNavigationActivity.class);


        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = CountryLanguageActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.file_Save),MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(getString(R.string.language),languagesave);
        editor.commit();


        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // Dynamically set the height for the items in list view
    private void resizeListView(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();
        int count = adapter.getCount();
        int itemsHeight = 0;
        // Your views have the same layout, so all of them have
        // the same height
        View oneChild = listView.getChildAt(0);
        if( oneChild == null)
            return;
        itemsHeight = oneChild.getHeight();
        // Resize your list view
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = itemsHeight * count;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heosI.png)

Comment: Need to pass the short form of language in your web service. Accourding to your short form you should get the data from web service. If your mobile application language is English then you must pass the short form "en" to your web service and if Arabic then you must pass the short form "ar"

Comment: is it right? @Mavya Soni...

Comment: check question...

Comment: 1. You have to set default value for **languagesave** variable 2. your method  **language();** first call then call new retrievedata().execute(); Sorrr for my bad english

Comment: you mean languagesave = english like that @ Mavya Soni

Comment: No , languagesave = "en"

Comment: if i set default value is english(en) the app change the language

Comment: but language selection is user choosen.then we set the default value english then how to changed?

Comment: Your code is not completed. First you do save your language or get language of device then call the your asynctask for that you save the language code in sharedpreference , when you come back to application again that time you should get the language code from sharedpreference.

Comment: frd can you give any examples pls?

Comment: i updated question again..check it.i already created language choose page.then how can i get user select language from another activity(this activity).

Comment: Please give me a mins.

Comment: ok.i wait.i want to say something.actually bad english is not bad.help needed some one  who can't help that the bad thing.thanks for helping me...

Comment: i checked.but i use language select option in listview.see the question again.i upadated again.

Answer (score 0):

**Check out my code :**

```
    Private void changeLanguage (final int position) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    if (position == 1) {
        final Locale myLocale = new Locale("ar");
        final Resources res = getResources();
        final DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        final Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        editor.putString("KEY","ar");
    } else {
        final Locale myLocale = new Locale("en");
        final Resources res = getResources();
        final DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        final Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        editor.putString("KEY","en");
    }
    editor.apply();
}
```

Put below code in Activity on-site

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        languagesave = sharedPreferences.getString("KEY", "en");
```

I have updated the post.

```
   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                changeLanguage(position);

                final Intent refresh = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(refresh);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

Comment: i checked.but i use language select option in listview.see the question again.i upadated again